# trigger/catch an event when the constructor method of an object is called

Tags: node.js, mongodb, events, mongoose

I'm new at Node.js and Mongoose and i would like to trigger/catch an event when an object constructor is launched.

I.E, I would like to send an email when a character is create like this:

```
controller.on('characterCreated', (mail, objectCreated) => {
    mailSenderFunction(mail, objectCreated);
});
```

I'm on a node.js structure Model/Service/Controller with MongoDB and mongoose like this:

characterModel.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const characterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
});

var Character = mongoose.model('Character', characterSchema);

module.exports = Character;
```

characterService.js

```
const Character = require('../models/modelCharacter.js');

function create(name, age) {
  return (new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const character = new Character();
      character.name = name;
      character.age = age;

      character.save((err) => {
        if (err) {
          reject({ status: 500, error: err });
        } else {
          resolve({ status: 202, data: character });
        }
      });
  }));
}

module.exports = {
    create,
};
```

characterController.js

```
const charService = require('../services/characterService');

function create(req, res) {
  if (req.body.name && req.body.age) {
      charService.create(req.body.name, req.body.age);
          .then((result) => {
              res.json(result.data);
              res.status(result.status).end();
          })
          .catch((error) => {
              res.status(result.status).end();
          })
  } else {
      res.status(404).end();
  }
}

module.exports = {
    create,
};
```

api.js:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const characterController = require('./routes/characterController');

router
    .route('/characters')
    .post(characterController.create);
```

My first idea is to do this :

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

const myEmitter = new EventEmitter();
myEmitter.on('myCustomEvent', (mail, data) => {
    mailSenderFunction(mail, objectCreated);
})
```

and use it like this:

characterService.js:

```
...
const character = new Character();
...
character.save((err) => {
...
    myEmitter.emit('myCustomEvent', mail, character);
})
...
```

But I saw that with mongoose we probably can hear about database events but I didn't find out how.

Is there a mongoose method or whatever to do this? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use pre for send ur mail like

```
characterSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    mailSenderFunction(mail, this);
    next();
});
```

this code is executed befor .save

if u need to send after a save see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-post

Comment: And logically i put this code in modelCharacter.js?

Comment: yes after ur model definition `let Char = new Schema({}) Char.pre('save', function(next){})` u can use all method name

Comment: Thanks :) it''s very effective

Comment: pleased to have helped you, dont forget to valide answere =)